# How do I add conditionally to a selection of cells in a pandas dataframe column when the the column is a series of lists?

Tags: python, list, pandas

Here is a simplified version of my current dilemma.

Here is the dataframe:

```
            x      y       A       B 
0           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0] 
1           ding   dong    [0, 1]  [0, 0] 
2           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0] 
3           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0] 
4           ding   dong    [0, 1]  [0, 0] 
5           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0] 
6           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0]
```

How do I add 1 to those cells in column B where  x != y. The cells are lists and the 1 should be inserted at index 1.

The resultant table would look as follows:

```
            x      y       A       B 
0           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0] 
1           ding   dong    [0, 1]  [0, 1] 
2           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0] 
3           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0] 
4           ding   dong    [0, 1]  [0, 1] 
5           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0] 
6           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0]
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What type of your `B` columns? Is it a `list` or `str`?

Comment: They are of type list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
def last_one(lst):
    lst[1] = 1

df[df.x != df.y].B.apply(last_one)
```

`df` before:

```
      x     y       A       B
0  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
1  ding  dong  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
2  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
3  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
4  ding  dong  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
5  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
6  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
```

and `df` after:

```
      x     y       A       B
0  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
1  ding  dong  [0, 1]  [0, 1]
2  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
3  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
4  ding  dong  [0, 1]  [0, 1]
5  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
6  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
```

Comment: Yes that works really well. I got so caught up thinking that it could be done using nested selection methods I had forgotten about passing a function to apply!

Answer (score 1):

You could `apply` lambda:

```
df[df.x != df.y].B.apply(lambda x: x[:-1] + [1])
```

Example:

```
In [283]: df
Out[283]:
      x     y       A       B
0  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
1  ding  dong  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
2  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
3  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
4  ding  dong  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
5  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
6  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]

mask = df.x != df.y
df.B[mask] = df.B[mask].apply(lambda x: x[:-1] + [1])

In [289]: df
Out[289]:
      x     y       A       B
0  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
1  ding  dong  [0, 1]  [0, 1]
2  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
3  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
4  ding  dong  [0, 1]  [0, 1]
5  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
6  ding  ding  [0, 1]  [0, 0]
```

Comment: I'm beginning to realise that this could be done in several different ways. The use of lambda saves me a function definition as well!

Comment: Note that the `lambda` function returns a new list instead of inserting (as ask for by the OP) into the existing one. This can have impact if the same list(s) is/are used somewhere else.

Comment: @orgelzyklus I realized that I missed some steps in asnwer which I perfomed in console. Take a look to the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks again to both for clarification.